# Homeomorphism between $R^n$ subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that there exists an homeomorphism between $X=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \, 0 < |x| \leq 1\}$ and $Y=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n| \, |y|\geq 1 \}$

I thought about the map $f:X \to Y$ defined as $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$, but I can't see that working, and I couldn't define an inverse function for it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $f(x)=\dfrac x{\|x\|^2}$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $x/|x|$ maps all points onto the sphere of radius $1$, not to the exterior of that sphere (i.e., radius "$\geq 1$").  You would be happier with (geometric) [inversion in a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_in_a_sphere).